# GNOME Shell extension themes not working

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-tweak-tool

I recently installed the Gnome Tweak Tool, and I am trying to install the theme "Faïence" so i navigate to the file and it says it has successfully installed, however the only thing that has changed is the  start bar across the top with the date/time, icons etc, the windows look exactly the same.

The only way i can change the appearance of the windows is by changing GTK+ themes, however they're all awful. I'm sure that GTK isn't much to do with the Shell themes, am i right? And yes i do have User Themes Extension installed. Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. In my experience many of the gnome-shell themes do not work as advertized and many are dependent on the version of gnome-shell you are running. You may want to contact the theme's author(s).

Comment: Thanks, I've tried about 10 different themes but to no avail, guess I'll give up on the idea of having a pretty work space! :/ Thanks for your reply anyway, much appreciated.

Comment: Can either one of you post this all as an answer, it'll help the next person trying to install themes to have a clear answer that this isn't working well right now.

Answer (score 2):

Gnome Shell themes change only the shell elements' appearance, like top bar, notification area, dash, etc. Window appearance should be modified by GTK themes.

I've taken a look at [this Faïence theme page](http://tiheum.deviantart.com/art/Gnome-Shell-Faience-255097456) and if it is the one you were talking about, you should do *more* than just change Gnome Shell theme. The author also recommends themes for GTK and icons, wallpaper and font.

So, in order to have the "advertised" appearance you have to install everything the author recommends. You also need to make sure your version of Gnome Shell is compatible with the theme you want.